# How to check specific elements of a list for a string value?

Tags: python, string, list

So im coding Tic Tac Toe

Ive created the environment as a list of 9 elements as shown below -

```
board=[' ']*9
```

I then place the X or O in the board

```
board[move-1] = 'X'
```

which works fine

The issue I'm having is after placing the X or O, im not able to check for the win condition. The output always returns as false [check the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XNjl.png)

```
if (board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == 'X') or (board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == 'O') :
    return winner==1
```

in the above code even when index 0,1 and 2 are X, it returns winner as false.

I think this is a simple string handling issue but I'm not really sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to put == 'X' at each test, like after board[0], after board[1] and so on!

Comment: `(board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == 'X')`  doesn't work how you think it does. You need to rewrite it like `(board[0] == 'X' and board[1] == 'X' and board[2] == 'X')`

Comment: Or more simply for your case: `(board[0] == board[1] == board[2])`

Comment: Yeah that fixed it! thanks guys!

the last one wont really work on my code i guess, coz it'll recognize ' ' elements as equal too

Comment: @TheRiddler a good point, I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cover vertical, horizontal and diagonal, you can build a list of axis positions for each direction and check if any of them map to XXX or OOO:

```
axes = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6)]
win = any(board[a]+board[b]+board[c] in ["XXX","OOO"] for a,b,c in axes)
```

If you want to make the computer play the game, you can create a move rating function that analyzes each playable positions and returns a number corresponding to how good the position is.

Here's an example:

```
from random import sample
axes = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6)] 

def isWin(board):
    return any(board[a]+board[b]+board[c] in ["XXX","OOO"] for a,b,c in axes)

def rating(position,play,board,level=3**6): # 3**6=Invincible, 3**4=hard, 3**1=Easy
    if board[position] != " " or level < 3: return 0
    newBoard = board[:position]+[play]+board[position+1:]
    if isWin(newBoard): return level*2
    nextRatings = [rating(p,"XO"[play=="X"],newBoard,level/3) for p in range(9)]
    return level-max(nextRatings,key=abs)

while True:
    board = [" "]*9
    player,computer = sample("XOXO",2)
    while True:
        for r in range(0,9,3):
            print("("+") (".join(board[r:r+3])+")",list(range(r+1,r+4)))
        available = [str(p+1) for p in range(9) if board[p] == " "]
        if isWin(board) or not available : break
        player = "XO"[player=="X"]
        if player == computer:           
            position = max(sample(range(9),9),key=lambda p:rating(p,computer,board))
            print(f"Computer plays {player} at {position+1}")
        else:
            while True:
                position = input(f"Position to play for {player}: ")
                if position not in available: print("Invalid position")
                else : position = int(position)-1; break
        board[position] = player
    print( f"{player}'s WIN !!!\n" if isWin(board) else "DRAW.\n")
```

*The `rating()` function goest through possible moves recursively returning a value that is smaller and smaller based on the number of moves needed to reach the end of game.  Each level's value is added or subtracted depending on which player's turn it is*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for the if statements: `all` will be `True` if all the 3 elements of `board` are either `X`. The same applies to `O`

```
if all(board[i]=='X' for i in range(3)) or all(board[i]=='O' for i in range(3)):
    return winner==1
```